# Are duplicates possible in MongoDB Sharded Cluster queries with skip/limit

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have noticed that if I execute the same query wihtout `sort` I can have different order of the resulting messages. I am wondering if I execute the same query with skip/limit to fetch different contiguous chunks of data. Is it possible that I can get the same documents multiple time? And if I execute the same query with the same skip and limit values multiple times will it always return the same messages just possibly in different order?

Comment: Here is note on [How mongos handles query modifiers sort, skip and limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharded-cluster-query-router/#how-mongos-handles-query-modifiers).

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one, it is still not clear to me if the duplicates can happen.